# How to recursively return all args inputs in C#

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm new to C# and have been testing ways to make the classic Hello World a little more dynamic. So far, I have it set up to test if there even is an args input but I can only get it to return the first without hard coding args[1] - args[x]. I tried messing around with the idea of using tuples but I'm clearly not sure

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Sup, {args[0]}");
    }

    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not think recursion is necessary to read all the passed in arguments. A `foreach` loop should do the trick… `foreach (string arg in args) { … }`. MSDN [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)

Comment: You misunderstand the meaning of the word *recursive*

Comment: What are your requirements, how will you use these args? It all depends and without knowing more, we can't provide an answer to help meet your requirements. Currently the question lacks these details and clarity.

Comment: @zaggler I think it is clear OP wants to access all arguments in a recursive manner. It is quite a standard approach if OP comes from the functional programming background - so I don't see it as really unclear question. Not necessary extremely practical, but we all started to learn recursion at some point and there is nothing wrong to use `Main` for that.

Comment: I suppose I wasn't clear with my direction. I think recursion is necessary (but may still be wrong) because I would love to be able to input names before writing a q to end program line that says hello to all names added with "and" inbetween them. I can obviously hard code an "and" to print after each name but then the final name would also have "and" proceeding it which is why I think I need a recursive call

Answer (score 3):

A very simple solution is to use [string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0) to do this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Sup, " + string.Join(", ", args));
```

This

> Concatenates the string representations of an array of objects, using the specified separator between each member.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly fine to call `Main` recursively - there is nothing special about it short of it being called at a startup.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if(args.Length == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello World");
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Sup, {args[0]}");

    if (args.Length > 1)
    {
        // recursively call Main with the remaining args, note that recursive 
        // call will not hit "Hello world" case as the tail always has at least one element
        Main(args.Skip(1).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Note that it is quite inefficient as it creates multiple arrays, passing index where to start could be an option but it would change signature of `Main` and as result will require one more function. If you simply want to access arguments `String.Join` as shown in other answer or `for(int i =0; i<args.Length; ++) {Console.Write(args[i]);}` would be much more common approach.